# GroovyDynamicElementReader cannot be resolved to a type when i build spring source

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I clone spring from  github and  import to IDEA,  when  i  build it ,get  ajc: GroovyDynamicElementReader cannot be resolved to a type. I don't know how resolved , so ask for help.

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yTOx.png)

Error:(389, 0) ajc: GroovyDynamicElementReader cannot be resolved to a type

Error:(389, 0) ajc: The method createDynamicElementReader(String) from the type GroovyBeanDefinitionReader refers to the missing type GroovyDynamicElementReader

Answer (score 0):

Check the following configuration of idea.

File-> Settings->Build,Excecution,Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler->Delegate to Javac

[image: Screenshot of setting enabled]